# Is Torta de Santiago supposed to be very moist?

Tags: baking, cake, pie, spanish-cuisine

Is a *Torta de Santiago* supposed to be moist?  I cook it on convection for full time but the cake is still moist, so much so that  my 95 year old mother-in-law cooks pieces I give her again! A couple of days later even!  I did get an internal temp of 190 F.  Any suggestions?  Cake tester seemed clean!

Answer (score 1):

Torta de Santiago should be moist, but I wouldn't describe it as very moist. Bear in mind that the standard presentation is to dust it heavily with icing sugar and then drench it in liquor when serving. If it's so moist that the icing sugar turns to icing, that's a problem. Otherwise, it would be moist from the liquor anyway.